# How to perform action after user logs in - php

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, modal-dialog

We have a page where logged in users can perform actions, however, this page can also be seen by non-logged in users. If the user tries to perform an action that requires the user to be logged in. We open up a dialog box containing a login/register box. The user then logs in and the page is refreshed, to show the logged in user.

My boss now wants the ability for the action to carry over once the user has logged in. When the login dialog box opens, it returns false in javascript and cancels the event for the guest.

For Example:

```
Guest -> clicks a follow button (must be logged in to do this action)
Guest -> sees login dialog box  
Guest -> enters credentials (sent via ajax)
Guest -> Page refreshes, Guest -> User
User -> the follow button click should carry over
```

I was thinking i could do an ajax request with all the data that was supposed to launch the event and store it in a $_SESSION. And then after the login, check the session variable to see it there is an event in the $_SESSION variable, if so then perform the action, else blow it off.

I am not using a framework. How is this normally accomplished. Session variables? The page must refresh so that certain variables are defined in the template.

How can i save the guests action and then perform it again on login?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to perform everything on client side. I mean, do not refresh the page immediately after the login action; perform the delayed action instead (follow in your example) using ajax too, then refresh your page if it's really required. Doing it this way, you won't have to store anything on server side in session.